# What's the best way to imitate carriage line?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I'm creating an app, where the user has 4 labels to type in using custom keyboard. I need to imitate the usual line in the textfield right after the last line, [image: like here]. Because my textLabels have corner radius, I cannot use border or shadow to solve the problem.

```
@IBOutlet weak var xField: InsetLabel!
@IBOutlet weak var yField: InsetLabel!
@IBOutlet weak var wField: InsetLabel!
@IBOutlet weak var hField: InsetLabel!
var textfields: [InsetLabel] = []

@IBOutlet weak var xSuppView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var ySuppView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var hSuppView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var wSuppView: UIView!
var suppViews: [UIView] = []

override func viewDidLoad(){
     super.viewDidLoad()
     textfields = [xField, yField, wField, hField]
     suppViews = [xSuppView, ySuppView, wSuppView, hSuppView]

for (index, view) in textfields.enumerated() {

        let carriageView = UIView()
        let width: CGFloat = 2.0
        let x = view.frame.maxX + width
        let y = view.frame.minY
        let height = view.frame.height
        carriageView.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 2, height: height)
        carriageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        carriageView.layer.cornerRadius = 2
        carriageView.backgroundColor = ColorConstants.carriageColor
        carriages.append(carriageView)
        suppViews[index].addSubview(carriageView)
        suppViews[index].translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: carriageView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: carriageView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: height)
        let topSpaceConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: carriageView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: suppViews[index], attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
carriageView.addConstraints([trailingConstraint, heightConstraint, topSpaceConstraint])


        view.sizeToFit()

        view.layer.masksToBounds = true
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 4
    }
}
```

That's why I created the identical views but with 0 corner radius and I've managed to get lines in place I need, but their position is fixed.

```
 let carriageView = UIView()
        let width: CGFloat = 2.0
        let x = view.frame.maxX + width
        let y = view.frame.minY
        let height = view.frame.height
        carriageView.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 2, height: height)
        carriageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        carriageView.layer.cornerRadius = 2
        carriageView.backgroundColor = ColorConstants.carriageColor
        carriages.append(carriageView)
        suppViews[index].addSubview(carriageView)
}
```

So I added constraint to this line programmatically for it to move with the width of my textLabel, but compiler doesn't like it. Seems like this constraint conflicts with storyboard constraints. Basicaly, I need to constraint 2 subviews of one superview by their common side. What am I doing wrong? This is the part of the error

```
    When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.
```

And btw is it a bad programming style to instantiate almost every view I have in my storyboard? Should I learn how to create everything programmatically?

**EDIT**

Error appears in the line, where I add constraints to the view.

```
carriageView.addConstraints([trailingConstraint, heightConstraint, topSpaceConstraint])
```

Is it ok, that I have a subview, created in storyboard, and a subview, created in viewDidLoad, and I am trying to constrain them in code?
[image: This is how the tree of the superview looks]

**EDIT**

I figured out, that creating this view programmatically was a bad idea, so I just added a view to each label with interface builder, than added just 1 constraint on leading space. Much easier to me, rather than the programmatic approach

Comment: Several alarms were ringing at first on this question. I was wrong. Up-voted. As to your last question - there's nothing wring with doing things in code only (particularly if using auto layout) so long as there is good reason. I needed to know if on an iPad things were portrait or landscape. At first I tried code because I wanted landscape left or right. It worked (in code) but then I added an app extension (Photo Editing) and my code wasn't getting hit. **That's good reason.** To me this sounds like a good reason also.

Comment: Additional note, now that I praised your question. The error you are getting suggest you are making constraint between two views not in the same node in the view hierarchy. This could be due to a few things - could you show the code where you have set up the view hierarchy (Be it in IB or addSubview)? Also, can you - if possible - point out the exact line of code giving you the error?

Comment: i dont understand your question. in every UITextField there is a cursor. can you make a screenshot how it current looks without your lines and with your lines?

Comment: I don't use uitextfields, I use uilabels due to the features I want to implement, that's why I don't have this line

Answer (score 0):

The problematic part is to understand when you are using autolayout and when you are using autoresizing (manual frame and autoresizing mask).

When you view is created in code, then its `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is `true` by default and when created in storyboard/xib with autolayout, then it's `false`.

Therefore:

You don't need to set

```
suppViews[index].translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

You have to choose whether you use a manual frame:

```
carriageView.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 2, height: height)
```

or constraints

```
let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: carriageView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: carriageView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: height)
let topSpaceConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: carriageView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: suppViews[index], attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
carriageView.addConstraints([trailingConstraint, heightConstraint, topSpaceConstraint])
```

If you want to set a manual frame, then don't set any constraints for `carriageView` and probably you should set autoresizing mask:

```
carriageView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleLeftMargin]
```

If you choose to use autolayout instead, you will have to

```
carriageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

and you will have to add some constraints to the superview:

```
carriageView.addConstraints([heightConstraint])
suppViews[index].addConstraints([trailingConstraint, topSpaceConstraint])
```

or using an utility function:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([trailingConstraint, heightConstraint, topSpaceConstraint])
```

Note that creating constraints in IB is much easier but you should still understand what's going on in code.